# Can IVIG treatment increase risk of infections?

Tags: immune-system, treatment, autoimmune-disease, immunosuppressant

Intravenous Immunoglobulins (IVIG) are often used to treat patients with impaired antibody production or autoimmune conditions[1]. However, according to this paper[2], it can also inhibit antibody production, inhibit B-cell differentiation, inhibit the complement system, and decrease cytokine levels. Is there an increased risk of getting infections while on IVIG treatment given its immunosupressive effects?

Sources:

1. https://www.uptodate.com/contents/intravenous-immune-globulin-ivig-beyond-the-basics#H4205572424
2. Jacob S, Rajabally YA. Current proposed mechanisms of action of intravenous immunoglobulins in inflammatory neuropathies. Curr Neuropharmacol. 2009;7(4):337-342. doi:10.2174/157015909790031166